# Linux PC: How to let other Linux devices copy files

Tags: python, linux, wifi, ftp-server

My application running under Linux creates four to seven data files in a directory whose name includes the client and datetime.These need to be copied by other devices - usually a Linux PC/laptop and potentially an Android phone. Currently the copying is done via a cable connection. I now need to make this wireless and more secure. The solution seems to be to run my PC as an FTP server and allow others to login to pull off the files. Ideally this should be coded in Python 2.7 although 'C' could be an option.

The majority of the information I can find, particularly in relation to Python, refers to using the PC as a client rather than a server. Are there Python extensions for running an FTP server or is there a better way of tackling this?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the most straightforward way would be to either use SSH (SCP), for which you only need SSH daemon enabled on the server machine, or to run a trivial webserver.

No coding required in either cases.